# Writing traversal methods for classes (TreeNode) that are designed to be inside (arbitrary) containers

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, containers

I have a class that (when simplified) looks like this:

```
class TreeNode
{
    ptrdiff_t sibling_offset, first_child_offset;
public:
    long whatever;

    // ...
};
```

The tree nodes must contain offsets instead of pointers, because it needs to be possible for them to be embedded in containers (like `std::vector`) that may reallocate their storage when necessary, without having to spend time re-linking all the nodes.

Now, if I have a suitably defined class `TreeIterator<Iter>` (perhaps defined as a `friend` of `TreeNode`) whose job it is to iterate over a `TreeNode`'s children, then *any STL-style client* of my class **should** be able to use it to iterate over the children of a node in a standard, STL fashion:

```
typedef std::vector<TreeNode> Tree;
Tree tree = ...;

TreeIterator<Tree::iterator> const root = tree.begin();
for (TreeIterator<Tree::iterator> i = root->begin(); i != root->end(); ++i)
{
    foo(i->whatever);
    process_further(i);
}
```

The trouble is, *`root->begin()` is impossible because the `TreeNode` doesn't know anything about the container it's in*.
(And it shouldn't! The only thing it cares about is that the container has suitable iterators.)

And yet, *I* (the author of `TreeNode`) am the only one who could possibly how to iterate over its children.

#### How do I resolve this issue, without restricting the type of the container that a `TreeNode` may be stored in?

Obviously this is easy if I force the user to use `std::vector`, but he should be free to use any arbitrary STL-compliant container.

Comment: Why do you need a container? Why not store the tree the old fashioned way, as a root node or pointer to it?

Comment: @KarthikT: Mainly for performance reasons, and also because containers make it easier to manage the tree in some cases (e.g. `std::copy`ing the entire tree is much easier).

Answer (score -2):

You just define functions begin() and end() in TreeNode. And then use them in your code.

```
    class TreeNode {
        ...
        std::vector<T>::iterator begin() {return vec.begin();}
        std::vector<T>::iterator end()   {return vec.end();}
        ...
    private:
        std::vector<T> vec;
    }
```